# 2006 Hummer H3 incompatibility bug with aftermarket radio - need advice on swap out

Tags: electrical, audio, aftermarket-upgrade, hummer, h3

I have a 2006 Hummer H3. I had a new radio installed this summer, the [Pioneer 4200NEX](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Car/NEX/AVH-4200NEX). I love the radio, but overtime some issues started to arise with my vehicle. Most notably, the car accessories would (at random) turn themself back on when the car was off. This caused my battery to keep dying. It also seems to be causing some odd passlock behaviors as well.

Anyways, I have had the car at two different dealerships over the past few months and both think the issue has to do with the aftermarket radio. Whenever they plug back into the stock radio harness it seems to resolves any immediate issues.

So just to see if the radio is indeed the culprit, I am looking for advice on which radio I should try instead - the tech who installed it thinks maybe its due to the BCM of the Hummer (as the '06 H3 was like guinea pig of the hummers he said) just not being compatible and they are going to let me swap it out or upgrade to nicer radio but I have zero car knowledge and am not sure what to suggest/try next.

Any/all advice would be appreciated, I have to swap-out / upgrade through Best Buy's store - so it would have to be something they carry.

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic problem. Aftermarket radios do not interface with the network or electronics of the vehicle. They tie into power, ground and speakers. If the problem is being caused by that fact that the factory radio is not tied into the network of the car, there is not an aftermarket radio in the world that will fix your problem.

GM is known for these types of issues. There is a generation of Impala where to have an aftermarket radio in the car the factory radio would have to be relocated to the trunk. There were mounting brackets and a harness specially made that sent power, ground and all the network connections to the trunk to connect to the radio. In the dashboard the harness split out the power, ground and speaker connections for the aftermarket radio. It is a distinct possibility that you may need to do something similar.